# SQL how to join multiple selects in columns versus rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `SQL Server` query:

```
DECLARE @data1 nvarchar(500) = '0.2,0.3,0.4'
DECLARE @data2 nvarchar(500) = '0.6,0.7,0.8'
DECLARE @data3 nvarchar(500) = '0.3,0.5,0.5'


SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @data1 , ',' ) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @data2 , ',' ) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @data3 , ',' )
```

The result is the following:

[image]

What I need is that `data1` is first column, `data2` is second column and `data3` is third column. I will have always same quantity of records for each data select.

[image]

> Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not guarantee the ordering of the results from `string_split()`.  Alas, alas.

For this reason, I recommend a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(nvarchar(max), null) as str, convert(nvarchar(max), v.rest) as rest, v.which, 0 as lev
      from (values (@data1, 1), (@data2, 2), (@data3, 3)) v(rest, which)
      union all
      select convert(nvarchar(max), left(rest, charindex(',', rest + ',') - 1)),
             convert(nvarchar(max), stuff(rest, 1, charindex(',', rest + ','), '')) as rest,
             which, lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select max(case when which = 1 then str end) as str1,
       max(case when which = 2 then str end) as str2,
       max(case when which = 3 then str end) as str3
from cte
where lev > 0
group by lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a47fb9b1efcf7a7c10f714e8a78c36bf) is a db<>fiddle.

In the future, they will hopefully add the `with offset`/`with ordinality` options available in other databases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` is indeed not what you need. I guess that `CROSS JOIN` is not what you need either , since, it generates a cartesian product of all 3 datasets, here resulting in 3^3 = 27 records being generated.

You do need some kind of `JOIN`. However we have to be careful when using `STRING_SPLIT` since it basically returns unordered records, as explained in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.

Here is one solution that orders each recordset by value, and then joins the results, row number wise. As a result, you only get 3 records, which I believe is what you want, with a predictable ordering:

```
SELECT x1.value, x2.value, x3.value
FROM 
    (
        SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value) rn FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @data1, ',' )
    ) x1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value) rn FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @data2, ',' )
    ) x2 ON x2.rn = x1.rn
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value) rn FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @data2, ',' )
    ) x3 ON x3.rn = x1.rn
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e39183ca22d820b4466bd0bd954f6e2d)** with your sample data returns:

```
value | value | value
:---- | :---- | :----
0.2   | 0.6   | 0.6  
0.3   | 0.7   | 0.7  
0.4   | 0.8   | 0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a `UNION`:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @data1 , ',' ) as Data1,
    STRING_SPLIT ( @data2 , ',' ) as Data2,
    STRING_SPLIT ( @data3 , ',' ) as Data3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
DECLARE @data1 nvarchar(500) = '0.2,0.3,0.4'
DECLARE @data2 nvarchar(500) = '0.6,0.7,0.8'
DECLARE @data3 nvarchar(500) = '0.3,0.5,0.5'

;with cte1(data, rn) as
(
select value, row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rn
from STRING_SPLIT(@data1, ',')
),
cte2(data, rn) as
(
select value, row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rn
from STRING_SPLIT(@data2, ',')
),
cte3(data, rn) as
(
select value, row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rn
from STRING_SPLIT(@data3, ',')
)
select t1.data as Data1, t2.data as Data2, t3.data as Data3
from cte1 t1
join cte2 t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn
join cte3 t3 on t3.rn = t1.rn
```